# Class cast Exception while using Comparable interface

Tags: java, classcastexception, comparable

When I am trying to execute the below code,the compiler is throwing error at line 13 as "java.lang.ClassCastException". Can someone let me know what's wrong with below code?

```
package chapter11;

import java.util.*;

public class ComparableExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Item[] items = new Item[3];
        items[0] = new Item(102, "Duct Tape");
        items[1] = new Item(103, "Bailing Wire");
        items[2] = new Item(104, "Chewing Gum");

        Arrays.sort(items);
        for (Item i : items) {
            System.out.println(i.getNumber() + ":" + i.getDescription());
        }
    }
}

interface Comparable {
    int compareTo(Object o);
}

class Item implements Comparable {
    private int number;
    private String description;

    public Item(int number, String description) {
        this.number = number;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public int compareTo(Object o) {
        Item i = (Item) o;
        if (this.getNumber() < i.getNumber())
            return -1;
        if (this.getNumber() < i.getNumber())
            return 1;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated,
Thanks!!

Comment: Why have you created your own `Comparable` interface?

Comment: Your compareTo method in the Item class can be simplified to: return this.number - i.number;   compareTo does not dictate that you return -1,1,or 0. You only need to return a pos/neg number or 0.

Comment: You're checking for `< i.getNumber()` twice. `1` will never be returned.

Comment: @Solace Frankly, no. That is not a good simplification. There is a chance of overflow when the result goes out of bounds. Best is to use `Integer.compare()` method.

Comment: @RohitJain That's a fair point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove your `Comparable` interface, and use the [`Comparable` interface from the Java api.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)
And also, maybe you can change

```
public int compareTo(Object o) {
        Item i = (Item) o;
        if (this.getNumber() < i.getNumber())
            return -1;
        if (this.getNumber() < i.getNumber())
            return 1;
        return 0;
    }
```

into :

```
public int compareTo(Object o) {
            Item i = (Item) o;
            if (this.getNumber() < i.getNumber())
                return -1;
            if (this.getNumber() > i.getNumber())
                return 1;
            return 0;
        }
```

Comment: In this case, fix the raw type.

Comment: `Comparable` is an interface. Both in OP code, and in standard Java API.

Comment: Removing Comparable interface doesn't change a thing. It still gives the same error(Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: chapter11.Item cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable) at Line 14..Also,changed the compareTo class

Comment: @RohitJain That's true, I wrote the answer without re-reading it